# Python not working in VScode - Error MSG: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.11

I saw a similar question posted but the solutions didn't help, since they said to restart.
Basically, I downloaded python 3.11, I made sure to add it to environment variables so the path is correct. Now CMD works fine if I search "python.exe". I will get it recgonized, but for some reason VScode doesn't recgonize python, and I am not sure what I should do. There was a similar question posted here, but it wasn't resolved.

Here is a picture of the error below.

I have saved this this python file as .py under my desktop. I have followed the same steps as youtubers and I stil get this error.

Please be detailed in simple in explanation since I am a novice at coding, and not the most tech savvy.
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You forgot to post the error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please ensure that you have installed [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python).
2. You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select interpreter" to choose the correct python interpreter.

Comment: I have done this, and it is listed as the correct one.

Comment: The most likely problem is still the environment variable. You can try to reinstall python. During installation, python will automatically add environment variables for you

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to File->Prefrences->Settings
2. generates a "User Settings" file
3. input the Python installation directory

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbd5Y.png)

Comment: This might be a good answer but it isn't clear why you would advise this vs. the typical instructions that are given - i.e., as in the VSCode getting started docs for python at [python-tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)

Comment: When I search user settings it doesn't allow me to type anything in it. it gives me a selection of common settings.

Comment: OK, i can now type in settings, but it seems that the interpreter path there is already correct. im unsure what i can switch it to

Comment: you can try this  extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).